# Python instance variable turns into class variable at runtime

Tags: python, oop, python-3.6, instance-variables, class-variables

using Python 3.6.9, when I run the following code the instance variable x spookily turns from an instance variable into a class variable. I can see that using the VSCode debugger (VSCode 1.51.1, Extension ms-python.python v2020.12.424452561). What is the cause?

```
class Image:
    pass


class Archive:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x


a = Archive(33)
a.x = Image
pass
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: No it doesn't. Maybe the debugger display is misleading, or you're reading it wrong.

Comment: Assigning the class `Image` to `a.x` is kind of weird. It's not clear why you're doing that.

Comment: I am using classes as Singletons somewhere in my code, and I simply want to reference them. I have objects of type Image and they have that instance variable "format" which shall reference one of these Singletons. But actually I think it does not matter why I want to do this.

Comment: I don't know why that's showing up under "class variables", but it's not a class variable. Maybe you edited your code without restarting Python or something.

Comment: The variable 'x' is storing the class object of Image, but still its an instance variable to Archive class

Comment: Sometimes I restart Python and this time i definitely did. Several times.

Comment: You're going to have to understand what the debugger means by "special variables" and "class variables" in the first place. Neither is a standard Python term. But the fact remains that `x` is still a class-valued instance attribute.

Comment: Ok, well then your IDE is wrong or using its own terminology

Comment: Note: FWIW, you can turn a class into a singleton like this: `my_class = my_class()` which turns the class into an instance of itself.

Comment: @martineau Is it really a singleton if you can instantiate it through the back door? `b = type(my_class)(); b is my_class` -> `False`

Comment: To prove that it's not a class attribute, try `Archive.x`. It'll error, `AttributeError: type object 'Archive' has no attribute 'x'`

Comment: @wjandrea: Sure, but that's how "we're all adults here" languages work. Sure, you could put in more protections (like making `__new__` not callable, and making the singleton by explicitly bypassing it using `object.__new__`), but whatever you do can always be worked around if needed by another programmer; that's a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @Shadow I guess I'm trying to say that it doesn't make the *class* a singleton, only the *name*. But whether that's important is another question, and I don't have enough experience with singletons to say. So, nvm.

Comment: @wjandrea: Of course there are ways around it. If that's what you meant, you should have said it in the first place.